# Copy-Paste Depending on Cell Values in Two Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a procedure that copies and pastes data from one workbook to another, contingent on 'labels' in two ranges.

Basically I would like to loop through one range, copy data next to each cell, then paste it elsewhere based on a corresponding cell value in the second range. I can do this with a bunch of IF statements, but if someone could suggest a more efficient option using variables or arrays, that would be much appreciated, as it obviously becomes tedious with large data sets.

Thank you.

```
For Each ColourCell In CopyRange

    If ColourCell.Value = "Blue" Then
    ColourCell.Offset(, 1).Copy
    PasteRange.Find("Aqua").Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
    End If

    If ColourCell.Value = "Red" Then
    ColourCell.Offset(, 1).Copy
    PasteRange.Find("Pink").Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
    End If

    If ColourCell.Value = "Yellow" Then
    ColourCell.Offset(, 1).Copy
    PasteRange.Find("Orange").Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
    End If

Next
```

Comment: To improve code that works as intended, I suggest you take the 5-minute tour over at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? (Untested)

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
    For Each ColourCell In CopyRange
        If ColourCell.Value = "Blue" Then copyAndPaste ColourCell, "Aqua"
        If ColourCell.Value = "Red" Then copyAndPaste ColourCell, "Pink"
        If ColourCell.Value = "Yellow" Then copyAndPaste ColourCell, "Orange"
    Next
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub

Sub copyAndPaste(rng As Range, strSearch As String)
    Dim PasteRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the releavnt range
    Set PasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    '~~> Try and find the Aqua, Pink, orange or whatever
    Set aCell = PasteRange.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> If found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(, 1).Copy
        aCell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever you are you using `.Find`, check if the cell was found else you will get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here my suggestion:

```
Dim findWord As String
Dim aCell As Range

For Each ColourCell In CopyRange

    Select Case ColourCell.value

        Case "Blue"
            findWord = "Aqua"

        Case "Red"
            findWord = "Pink"

        Case "Yellow"
            findWord = "Orange"

        Case Else
            findWord = ""

    End Select

    If findWord <> "" Then

        Set aCell = PasteRange.Find(What:=findWord, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then 
            ColourCell.Offset(, 1).Copy      
            aCell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

    End If

Next ColourCell
```

Comment: Do not use `.Find` like that :)

Comment: OK..I will modify. This is for Just suggestion.

Comment: '+1 great :) Now one thing, the `.Find` will still run if the `ColourCell.value` doesn't match Aqua,Pink or Orange ;) and hence a separate sub would have been nice

Comment: Cheers, only problem is in my real-world application of this procedure, I'm working with source ranges that contain many more cells than the ones I need to copy; I only want to copy the relevant ones.

Comment: Right Siddharth Rout, It need checking.

Comment: The main different between Siddharth and Me is using IF..ELSE and SELECT .. CASE. So, MJV you can use both answer.

Comment: No that is not the "main" difference :) the main difference is that I am copying and pasting only when it is required :)